# onsen-ui with phonegap: push page on app ready

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I check on device.ready the local storage whether the user is already logged in or not. Then I need to navigate either to "home.html" or "login.html" but I always get the reference error "Uncaught ReferenceError: ons is not defined".

```
ons.navigator.pushPage('home.html');
```

I tried also with window.onload or $(document).ready but I always get the same error.
Button clicks works fine.

Thanks in advice,
Kornel

Comment: seems like onset ui is not defined in the imports

Comment: You should use 'ons' object in the navigator scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ons.ready liste for cordova deviceready event and onsen loaded

```
ons.ready(function(){

   myNavigator.pushPage('home.html');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. One is a scope of Navigator and the other is timing.
Unfortunately the current Onsen-UI (ver 1.0.4) does not have a trigger the page is loaded.
You must wait until the page of navigator has been loaded.

For example,

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkScope();
    }

    function checkScope() {
        var element = document.querySelector( ".navigator-container");
        var scope = angular.element( element ).scope();
        if (scope && scope.getCurrentNavigatorItem && scope.getCurrentNavigatorItem() ) {
            scope.pushPage("page2.html");
        } else {
            setTimeout( checkScope , 100 );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the pushPage event works but I need to pass a parameter but I get an error on the pushed page. I use your code but instead the "scope.pushPage" event I inserted "scope.getCurrentPage().options.foo" but I get an exception "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nobody who could help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead:

```
menu.setMainPage('home.html', {closeMenu: true});
```